# Could not find writer for content-type application/octet-stream type:

Tags: java, gradle, stream, resteasy, octetstring

I'm trying to turn an **old** project into a gradle, but i get the error above.

`if (asynchronous) {
                ClientResponse resp = request.post();
                System.out.println("status: " + resp.getStatus());
                System.out.println("status phrase: " + resp.getResponseStatus().getReasonPhrase());
            }
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not find writer for content-type application/octet-stream type: edi.EdiEncrypter`

I get that error in line request.post();

Here is my resteasy dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'jaxrs-api', version: '2.3.0.GA'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '2.3.0.GA'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-crypto', version: '2.3.0.GA'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-multipart-provider', version: '2.3.0.GA'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxb-provider', version: '1.2.1.GA'
```

Any ideas on what **version of restessay** can help me or something else ?

Comment: Hi Dionisios,  Were you able to resolve the issue ? I am also seeing similar issue in 1 of my application.

Comment: Hello, I didn't resolve this issue yet, I rewrite the whole project.